# How can I issue a Let's Encrypt certificate with Ansible when 'challenge_data' cannot be found?

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to use the Ansible `acme_certificate` module to acquire a Let's Encrypt TLS certificate.

I have successfully generated the private keys, CSRs, etc, and then started the challenge using the following task:

```
- name: Start challenge
  acme_certificate:
    acme_version: 1
    account_key_src: /etc/letsencrypt/account/account.key
    challenge: http-01
    csr: /etc/letsencrypt/csrs/{{ item }}.csr
    dest: /etc/letsencrypt/certs/{{ item }}.crt
    fullchain_dest: /etc/letsencrypt/certs/fullchain_{{ item }}.crt
  with_items:
  - www.example.com
  register: acme_challenge
```

I then attempt to satisfy the `http-01` challenge using:

```
- name: Implement challenge
  copy:
    content: "{{ acme_challenge['results']['challenge_data']['www.example.com']['http-01']['resource-value'] }}"
    dest: "/var/www/html/{{ acme_challenge['results']['challenge_data']['www.example.com']['http-01']['resource'] }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r
```

However, this results in the following error:

`The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'challenge_data'`

I have tried accessing the `acme_challenge` variable in different ways, for example using `{{ acme_challenge.challenge_data['www.example.com']['http-01']['resource'] }}`, as well of various other combinations of square brackets and dots.

I've also copied the example of accessing the variable directly from the Ansible documentation, [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/letsencrypt_module.html) and [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/acme_certificate_module.html), but that gives the same error.

After around 3 hours of trying I cannot read the challenge data at all. I've used a `debug` statement and I can confirm that it's all there properly, I just can't read the variable with this syntax.

Is this a known problem, or does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by the fact that I was starting the Let's Encrypt challenges using a `with_items` loop. From [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables):

> When using register with a loop, the data structure placed in the variable during the loop will contain a results attribute, that is a list of all responses from the module. For a more in-depth example of how this works, see the Loops section on using register with a loop.

The solution is to have a separate task for each Let's Encrypt challenge, rather than having them all in one.

Answer (score 1):

For those searching, I found this post while experiencing the same issue.  I was able to resolve this by adding the array index to my loop:

```
  copy:
    content: "{{ acme_challenge_your_domain['results'][ansible_loop.index0]['challenge_data'][item.hostname]['http-01']['resource_value'] }}"
    dest: "/var/www/{{ item.hostname }}/{{ acme_challenge_your_domain['results'][ansible_loop.index0]['challenge_data'][item.hostname]['http-01']['resource'] }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r
  loop: "{{ hosted_sites }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
    extended: yes
```

The specific changes here being converting with_items to a loop and adding the loop_control parameter extended.  This allows for usage of ansible_loop.index0.